# How to configure view and phtml file to show images in gallery?

Tags: zend-framework

I have configured my xml, controller, model.
But I am having problem with view and phtml file.
Please tell me how should I configure my view and phtml file to show images.

Here's the code of controller and model

Model:

```
public function getImageUploadPath() {
    return Fox::getUploadDirectoryPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'gallery' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'images' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
}

public function getImageUploadUrl() {
    return Fox::getUploadDirectoryUrl() . '/' . 'gallery' . '/' . 'images' . '/';
}

public function getAllFolderImages() {
    $dir = $this->getImageUploadPath();
    $files=array();
    $i=0;
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if((filetype($dir . $file)=='jpg')||(filetype($dir . $file)=='png')||(filetype($dir . $file)=='gif')||(filetype($dir . $file)=='jpeg')){
                $files[$i]=$file;
                $i++;                    
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
public function getImagesAction(){
    return Fox::getModel('gallery/images')->getAllFolderImages();
}
public function getImagePathAction(){
    return Fox::getModel('gallery/images')->getImageUploadUrl();
}
```

Please tell me how to configure the view and phtml file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zend if you have a Controller named `newController` and action named `indexAction()` the default view is `new/index.phtml`. That means if you are creating a new controller you have to create a folder named 'new' in `view/scripts/` and a file named 'index.phtml' inside 'new' folder. New folder for each new Controller and new file for each Action()